Could the Screenshot of the Week container on the main site say "Vote now" instead of "Submit your photo" once it's time to vote?
The Screenshot of the Week container on the main site always says "Submit your photo", no matter what stage of the contest(?) we're in.
This is obviously a little bit misleading if it says to submit your photo while we're in the voting phase of the contest.
Could we change it so that while we're in the voting phase, it says something along the lines of "Vote now"?

I'm going to say the answer is no - for now.
This is because there is no binding mechanism that would otherwise tell the widget to switch between "Submit your photo" and "Vote Now."  We would need a Stack Exchange employee/developer to implement such a feature for us.  We (the moderators of the site) cannot control what the text says for that button.
Maintaining the Screenshot of the Week Meta posts and the widget is entirely a manual effort. I could see some sort of manual way for us moderators to change the text (perhaps via some sort of radio button control), but again, that would require a Stack Exchange employee to implement, and this kind of change is too minor for them to probably spare time to at the moment.

I marked this post as [meta-tag:status-review], which should make it visible to SE staff who can further make a decision on what to do for this, but I don't see anything changing for this in the near future.

Yeah, thought so. It would be nice though. I’ll wait to accept until it’s been more than 10 minutes though.

Also, correct me if I'm wrong @TimmyJim, but theres no switch from a 'submission time' to a 'vote time'. Submissions are open from the start of the contest to the last minute. Same for votes. You can vote on a submission from the first minute one submission is made to the last minute before close.

@Fredy31 technically yes - but we usually do a week of submissions, followed by a week of voting. During the week of voting, its usually discouraged to submit any screenshots, since it no longer would be during the submission time frame.  But there is no built in mechanism to prevent a user from submitting a screenshot at anytime of the competition technically.  We usually just comment on the posts if someone does this that they missed the window.

Yeah I missed that technicality. To me in the SOTW contest it always seem the sooner you throw in your submission, the best chance you got anyways.

@Fredy31 It does say on the post thought that once the first week has passed, submissions are locked. The title changed to “Submissions closed - vote now” anyway.

Maybe while they’re updating it /s they can let me pin it to my SO sidebar instead of those widgets
